# Building iOS project with Xcode with different resource folder

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building multiple app with the same source code but different resource folder. 
How can I configure this, such that profile A will use ResourceA folder. and profile B use ResourceB folder?  I am thinking to make it more automatic way, instead of replacing the Resource folder each time of build.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you drag the resource folder in to Xcode just make sure that only add it to the target that you want those resources for.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the desired traget's while adding Resource folder via **Add to Targets** section.